# Changing the locations of shell folders from registry paths is not taking effect

Tags: c#, registry, special-folders, microsoft-file-explorer

I am trying to change the location of windows specials folders (documents, downloads, pictures, etc.) from windows registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders
```

[image]

But, these are not taking any effect to actual locations of the special folders.

[image]

How I can change it programmatically?

I have tried to change it like this in registry.

```
string root = SID + "\\" + @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders";
try
{
    RegistryKey foldersKey = Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(root, true);
    if (foldersKey != null)
    {
        foldersKey.SetValue("{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}", AppHelper.GetApplicationUserProfile() + @"\Downloads");
        foldersKey.SetValue("Personal", AppHelper.GetApplicationUserProfile() + @"\Documents");
        foldersKey.SetValue("My Music", AppHelper.GetApplicationUserProfile() + @"\Music");
        foldersKey.SetValue("My Pictures", AppHelper.GetApplicationUserProfile() + @"\Pictures");
        foldersKey.SetValue("My Video", AppHelper.GetApplicationUserProfile() + @"\Videos");
        //foldersKey.SetValue("Desktop", AppHelper.GetApplicationUserProfile() + @"\Desktop");
        foldersKey.SetValue("Favorites", AppHelper.GetApplicationUserProfile() + @"\Favorites");
        foldersKey.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Logger.Error(e);
}
```

I would like to change the location of special folders in file explorer, when ever the registry path of these folders are changed. How I can do this in my C# code?

Comment: The PC should be restarted in order for the registry to be loaded with the changes.

Comment: It's not changing after PC is rebooted.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shsetknownfolderpath

Comment: How I can use SHSetKnownFolderPath any code example?